# json_encode not working with strip_tags

Tags: php, json

I want to insert some input a list into JSON but it looks very strange. I use `strip_tags` to fix a memory leak. Here is the code and the outputted JSON

Code:

```
<?php
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
include_once('libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://hugo.events/event/2017');
// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('ul#EventLandinLineUpList') as $element)
    $encoded = strip_tags($element);
    echo json_encode($encoded);
```

And this is the JSON that has been outputted:

```
"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFEDDE LE GRAND\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tKENSINGTON\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTYPHOON\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSUNDAY SUN\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBL\u00d8F\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `strip_tags` does not remove/condense whitespace.

Comment: How do I remove those whitespaces?

Comment: I'm curious, how does `strip_tags` fix a memory leak?

Comment: @FirstOne I have no idea. But it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used: preg_replace.

This was the final code:

```
<?php
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
include_once('libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://hugo.events/event/2152');
// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('ul#EventLandinLineUpList') as $element)
    $stripped = strip_tags($element);
    $stripped = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $stripped);
    echo json_encode($stripped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()` to remove the whitespace there.

Comment: Thanks. Eventually I used preg_replace, but still lthanks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Not sure about strip_tags fixing a memory leak mind....(!?)

Comment: @stevensmith, you should post an answer with your solution too

Comment: @FirstOne There you go